# Does MVC design means you have to separate mysql from php code?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, mysqli

Does MVC really means you have to separate => View aka design (html css) => controler (php code), model (mysql code into classes etc.)???

Are there not alternatives? Wondering because I would really like to avoid separating php code and mysqli as right now it's sooo easy to work on it (got used to it).

Comment: While it almost *never* happens your application should be portable enough to switch out the persistance layer (mysql) with an alternative with minimal issues (mssql, postgresql, etc). It's a good goal to follow that yields positive latent results even though the actual case of moving databases almost never happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does MVC really means you have to separate => View aka design (html
>   css) => controler (php code), model (mysql code into classes etc.)???

No.

MVC is about [separation pf concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). It separates presentation layer from model layer. And within presentation layer - it separates handling of input (controllers) from handling of output (views).

The model in MVC is **not a databases abstraction** or collection of queries. Instead it is a layer that contains several groups of classes. The major groups are [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject), [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) and [services](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html). The model in MVC is all these things taken together.

<kbd>Longer explanation: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208)</kbd>

> **Note:** do not confuse MVC's model with [domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model), which is the accumulated knowledge and vocabulary for specifica application. The part of domain model, that can be encompassed in code, is implemented using domain objects.

View is not html and css. Views in MVC are classes that contain the UI logic for the application. THey acquire data from model layer and then, based in this information, choose which templates to use for producing a response.

<kbd>Longer explanation: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596704/727208)</kbd>

Controllers are not some mystical "php code". They are part of application that takes user input, and based on that alter the state of model layer and (in rare cases) state of current view.

> Are there not alternatives? Wondering because I would really like to
>   avoid separating php code and mysqli as right now it's sooo easy to
>   work on it (got used to it).

The point is NOT separating SQL from PHP.

The [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle simply means that each part of your application should be dealing with one specific aspect.

And, if you try to implement MVC architecture, it will NOT mean that you separate sql from php, but that you separate business logic from persistence logic. Both of those would be written in PHP. But the trick is - MySQL is not the only form of storage. Data can also be stored in session, in cache, in noSQL, in files, in SOAP, etc. If you have separated business logic from persistence logic, then you can add caching to your existing application without rewriting the whole thing.

Also ...

There are more architectures then just MVC and [Big Ball of Mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud) (which was advertised by people who talked about Drupal and Joomla).

You have [MVP](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf), [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), [n-Tier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture), [DCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data,_context_and_interaction), [EDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) and many others. And all these will be adhering to [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle .. but the result that they come up with will be different.

> **P.S.:** If you actually want to learn about MVC, I would recommend for you to start going through materials from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16356866/727208). It will start by introduction to simple concepts and gradually build up to ideas that you have to grasp to actually start working with MVC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you definitely want to separate HTML and CSS from business logic.

Most frameworks use an ORM or something similar to abstract building queries but still give you the option to write plain SQL. I would recommend to use an ORM like doctrine2 for example over plain SQL. If you use any SQL directly the model would most likely the right place to put it into.

MVC exists for a reason, [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). This makes sure that your application becomes easy to maintain because every part of it should be easy to replace and not depend on each other to much. You want to avoid strong coupling. MVC is a pattern that helps you with that.

And like tttpapi said, there other ways to do it, but honestly, I personally think that specially Wordpress for example is a horrible clutter. I don't like Drupal or Joomla as well. The code base feels like working with 10 year old clutter compared to a modern well written application following the MVC pattern.

This is a little about discipline es well, I've seen totally messed up applications as well because people did not pay attention to separation of concerns and didn't follow the MVC pattern.

Comment: While I agree with what you say, I must state that the ORM is not enough of an abstraction - and depending on the complexity of the system you should abstract it more. Basically you want to use the Repository Pattern or a Data Mapper for really complex systems. Business logic shouldn't implement Persistence Logic at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is always up to you.
You always can find way how to use MVC as nonMVC. (example is Joomla here you can use just view with all code in it)

Or you can use systems that are not MVC bases such as Drupal.

But the MVC is here for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, yes MVC means exactly that.
However MVC is just a design pattern, and not a holy writ.

There are many variations available to you. I myself initially thought MVC to be restrictive and confusing, but in fact it was the particular MVC based framework i choose that had these failings.

There are many lightweight, flexable frameworks available. Take a look at https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree as a nice example, in particular the database section. You wont think mysqli is simple in comparison