# Design pattern to work with API service

Tags: api, design-patterns, module

I need to develop a script to work with an API service (RESTfull) class library.
The final product should be a module with some user interface. This module I should import into a work project.
So I searched design patterns to create my file structure.

The first option pattern **Gateway** with files structure like here:

```
--/Classes
----/libApiClasses
-------(files Class API service here)
----Gateway.php - work with libApiClasses
----Log.php
--/Html - html templates for response
----template1.html 
----template1.html
----....
--index.php - work with class Gateway.php & Log.php
```

The second idea uses a default MVC pattern, with thin controller & model and components folder to work with library API Classes:

```
--/Controller
----CMain.php
--/Components
----(files Class API service here)
--/Model
----MGateway.php
----MLog.php
--/View
----template1.html 
----template1.html
--index.php
```

The real plus MVC, it's very popular. Everybody know it.
p.s Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

I used MVC pattern and it really create solution.

Thanks this posts:

- [How should a model be structured in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc)
- [Understanding MVC Views in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594907/understanding-mvc-views-in-php)