# Echoing in Model View Controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC and I need to echo data from my database in View. Can anyone help me with that? Here is the code:

Controller:

```
class Index extends Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    //echo 'We are in index';
  }

  function index(){
    $this->view->render('index/index');
  }

  function get(){
    $this->model->get();
  }
}
```

Model:

```
class Index_Model extends Model {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function get()
  {
    $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM data');
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::);
    $sth->execute();
    $sth->fetchAll();
  } 
}
```

How to echo in View?

Comment: where do you want to echo and what do you want to echo.. mention  please

Comment: In my model I need to take data from my database, and use controller to echo all results in my view file. I am new to MVC, and I dont know how to do that

Comment: Maybe this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596704/727208