# How to pass multiple objects to a template?

Tags: php, templates

I am trying to understand the MVC method with the use of OOP. However it seems like I've hit the wall here.

I am trying to pass multiple objects to the view. But all I can do so far is pass just one object. The ideal result would be passing multiple objects, while keeping the names that are assigned to them in the controller.

The render, start and end functions in the View class go something like this:

```
public function render($viewName, $data){
    $viewAry = explode('/', $viewName);
    $viewString = implode(DS, $viewAry);
    if(file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS .  'views' . DS . $viewString . '.php')){
        include(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS .  'views' . DS . $viewString . '.php');
        include(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'views' . DS . 'layouts' . DS . $this->_layout . '.php');
    }else{
        die('The view \"' . $viewName . '\" does not exist.');
    }
}

public function content($type){
    if($type == 'head'){
        return $this->_head;
    }elseif ($type == 'body'){
        return $this->_body;
    }
    return false;
}

public function start($type){
    $this->_outputBuffer = $type;
    ob_start();
}

public function end(){
    if($this->_outputBuffer == 'head'){
        $this->_head = ob_get_clean();
    }elseif($this->_outputBuffer == 'body'){
        $this->_body = ob_get_clean();
    }else{
        die('You must first run the start method.');
    }
}
```

And this is how would the controller look like:

```
public function indexAction(){
    $items =  $this->PortalModel->getItems();
    $collections =  $this->PortalModel->getCollections();

    $this->view->render('home/index', $items);
}
```

So this is how I get the one $data object to the view and loop trough it.
But how could I store multiple results from the database to the view?

Comment: Maybe `$this->view->render('home/index', ['items' => $items, 'anotherObject' => $anotherObject/*, etc*/]);`

Comment: I get it, but how are theese accessible to the view. If I `var_dump($items)` I gat an undefined variable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC and what you have there is **not** a view. Just read this: http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Comment: So you think I posted something about templating? What i postet is not a view, its a core class where i store my View functions. A view is made out of HTML and some or none php.

Comment: @Nikola Kail Cava Popović how did you accessed $items at first place?

Comment: @NikolaKailCavaPopović maybe read this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594907/understanding-mvc-views-in-php/16596704#16596704 .. and, yes, what you wrote about is actually templating. You just do not seem to realize it.

Comment: @tereško Is it not so, that the View class takes care of the templating?

Comment: No, that is done by templating engines (either self-written or  third-party ones, like Twig). And what you have there is a simplified templating engine.

Comment: @NikolaKailCavaPopović yes .. I know, what it says. So, basically, it's what's in your "controller"  :D

Comment: @tereško I do not understand what are you trying to accomplish here. Are you trying to say that what I have written would never be used in an MVC pattern?

Comment: I am trying to tell you, that what you have here has nothing to do with MVC. What you call "view" is a template, your "controller" contains all of the actual logic and what you refer to as "models" are probably active-record style table abstractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an array of variables into view instead of one variable.

```
public function indexAction(){
    $variables = [
        'items' => $this->PortalModel->getItems(),
        'collections' => $this->PortalModel->getCollections()
    ];

    $this->view->render('home/index', $variables);
}
```

Comment: So usefull :D Awesome

Comment: Hmmm...how would this then be used if i passe just one record from the table?