# MVC consideration in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

Is it right to use php code or blade code in view file using laravel?

for MVC consideration is it better to sepearate front end code like HTML with any server side code and keep them in corresponding controller file ?

for example using like this:

in view:

```
    <table>
      <Loop>  <!-- instate of using @foreach -->
        <tr>
          <td>
            <-UserId->
          </td>
          <td>
            <-UserName->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </Loop>
    </table>
```

in controller:

```
    $html = view('page');
    $loop_section=my_own_func_to_get_loop_tag_content($html);

    //edit loop_section var with php foreach and return resault to  $modified_loop_section var

    $html=str_replace($loop_section,$modified_loop_section,$html);

    return $html;
```

**Updated:**

above code is just an example way that isn't seemed a good way.
but i look for better way to separate any php code (including if foreach etc) with html code in view file without using a custom tag and code?

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of MVC, and needlessly complicates everything. Use Blade's `@foreach` etc. as documented - that's entirely normal in MVC. What you *shouldn't* be doing is stuff like your database queries in the view - they should be done in the controller and *passed* to the view.

Comment: I use that for avoiding problems in team works, so i did separate any php (or blade) codes (like foreach) from view file that writing by html programmers. my question is this way logical? or have anyone a better way?

Answer (score -2):

Yes you should definitely use `Blade` code in your templates. So function `my_own_func_to_get_loop_tag_content` should be processed in **template file**, but it should only show data. All business logic (such as DB querying, sorting, calculations, ...) should be done in your controllers. **View is only for displaying data**, so there shouldn't be any logic.

Comment: `@foreach`, `@if`, etc. are logic, but they (potentially) belong in the view.

Comment: So you mean if we have a person to work on html and another person to work on php , they must work together exactly in a view file ?? Is it logic? why dont we separate view with any php  code completely?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, absolutely agree. I didn't mean this. Of course you need `@foreach` and `@if` in your views but only for conditional displaying some html parts, not for tasks like e.g. loading data from db based on if condition

Comment: imagen that a person that works on html dont know any php code.I wonder for mvc consideration isnt better to use all php codes (including if foreach etc) outside of html file ?

Comment: @AdelLotfi No. Your custom tags that don't exist in HTML would be equally confusing, with the added bonus of confusing the PHP users too. **Everyone** would be confused by your proposed approach - it introduces a bunch of complexity and confusion with little benefit.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes i agree. i'm making a confusing way to html and php users with custom tags. and that's why i asked a question here to hope that a person show me a good way  that have separated php and html completely in view file and without any custom tag and code...

Comment: @AdelLotfi I don't think that's a reasonable goal. Anyone messing around in the code of a Laravel app should have at least a basic understanding of PHP/Laravel. You can teach a designer Blade's templating system.

Comment: @JozefCipa you might find this to be a relevant read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596704/727208